# Storing multiple files on database PHP

Tags: php, ios, swift

Hello I am uploading multiple images from my ios swift app.

But my problem is I cannot manage to store them in my DB, and I'm pretty sure It is to do with my PHP code... It works fine for 1 image, but cannot get it to work for 2 images...I have tried using loops, but nothing worked, probably my fault for implementing them incorectly.

Here is my php code, if anyone can help it's much appreciated!!

```
// STEP 2.3 Move uploaded file
$folder = $folder . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $folder)) {


    $returnArray["message"] = "Post has been made with picture";
    $blogImage1 = "http://**********/Files/Posts/ImgPosts/" .$id . "/" . $Title . "-". $uuid . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]); //

} else {
 //$returnArray["message"] = "Post has been made without picture";
 $Image1 = "";

}
```

Swift Code

```
func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: NSMutableDictionary?,boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData()

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {

            if(value is String || value is NSString){
                body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
            }
            else if(value is [UIImage]){
                var i = 0;
                for image in value as! [UIImage]{
                    let filename = "image\(i).jpg"
                    let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1);
                    let mimetype = "image/jpg"
                    //"\(key)\(i)"
                    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\(i)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
                    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
                    body.append(data!)
                    body.appendString("\r\n")
                    i += 1;
                }


            }
        }
    }
    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
    //        NSLog("data %@",NSString(data: body, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!);
    return body
}
```

If anyone needs to see more code, please let me know.

Comment: what is the second file name which you are posting?

Comment: @AlbertAkki it is also "file" I am uploading an array..But I can change it to "file0" (for the first image) and "file2"(for the second image) what do you reccomend? would you like to see the swift code?

Comment: yes do the change file name and try. and also please update the php code  that you need to write upload code two time for two file

Comment: I have change the name and added my swift code above so you can see(the file name change here "\(key)\(i)"). Do I just repeat the same code I have in php and just change the "file" names? could you give me a quick example/answer for saving 2 posts please?

Comment: @AlbertAkki  AlbertAkki

Comment: try to add `http://pastebin.com/29LPbg3U` code at php side

Comment: What does that do? and where?

Comment: replace it with php code and do change the file name from where you are posting with `file0` and `file1`

Comment: @AlbertAkki I replaced it but, it doesn't seem to find the "file1", but if I remove the second 1 and just leave the first 1 and change the "file0" to "file1" it does upload the correct image.

Comment: If i have 2 of the code I added above it doesn't work, but if I just put 1 in and change the "file0" to "file1" it uploads the second image

Comment: you can change the file name to `file2` if you are passing with it

Comment: I have "file0" which is the first image in the first part of the code, and in the second part(which is identical to the first part, apart from "file0" is now "file1") but it doesn't seem to move "file1". But If I remove the second part and just leave the first part and change "file0" to "file1" it does upload the second image...So the images are there...Can't understand why this isn't working!!

Comment: Your problem might be in this line:  `$folder = $folder . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);` When you use it the second time you  no longer have the _clean_ folder name.

Comment: @moni_dragu Thanks but figured it out, will be posting the answer soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by changing the current code in my PHP file for adding the image to this, to add multiple images from an UIImage array in my IOS app:

```
foreach ($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] as $index => $tmp_name) {
    $filePath = $folder . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][$index]);
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $filePath)) {
        // rename like you want to
        $filePath = "http://**.**.***.**/Files/Posts/IMGPosts/" .$id . "/" . $Title . "-". $uuid . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][$index = 0]); //
        $Image1 = $filePath; //
        $filePath = "http://**.**.***.**/Files/Posts/IMGPosts/" .$id . "/" . $Title . "-". $uuid . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"][$index = 1]); //
        $Image2 = $filePath; //
```

Hope this helps other people too, for any further detail just comment below!